# RxJava wait for single Event, RxJava

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactive

How do you wait for a single value to come on an observable with a timout?

I am looking for something like:

```
Observable<Acknowledgement> acknowledgementObservable;
port.send(new Message());
Optional<Acknowledgement> ack = acknowledgementObservable.getFirst(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by adding .timeout() and .onErrorComplete() .blockingGet()

So in this example it would be:

```
    Acknowledgement ack = acknowledgementObservable
                              .firstElement()
                              .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                              .onErrorComplete()
                              .blockingGet();
```

If the timeout is hit, ack will be null.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert `Observable` to `CompletableFuture` as described in [Converting between Completablefuture and Observable](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/11/converting-between-completablefuture.html):

```
Observable<Acknowledgement> acknowledgementObservable;
port.send(new Message());
CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
acknowledgementObservable
    .doOnError(future::completeExceptionally)
    .single()
    .forEach(future::complete);
```

Then, wait for the event using timeout:

```
Acknowledgement ack = future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

It throws `TimeoutException` if timeout occurs.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause a memory leak in case of a TimeoutException?
How about acknowledgementBuffer..getObservable().timeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).blockingFirst() ?

Comment: You told nothing about `acknowledgementBuffer`, so I cannot say anything about this suggestion.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant acknowledgementObservable.timeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).blockingFirst()..